# Is the set of sub-dcpos a dcpo (directed-complete partial order)?

Tags: order-theory, posets

$\newcommand{\sub}{\mathrm{sub}}$Given a dcpo (directed-complete partial order) $\mathcal{X} = (\le, X)$, consider the set $\mathcal{X}^{\sub}$ of all sub-dcpos of $\mathcal{X}$.  Can one define a partial order  $\le_{\sub}$ on $\mathcal{X}^{\sub}$ such that $( \le_{\sub}, \mathcal{X}^{\sub})$ is a dcpo?

I suppose you may add, what conditions on $\mathcal{X}$ allow us to define $\le_{\sub}$ on $\mathcal{X}^{\sub}$ such that $( \le_{\sub}, \mathcal{X}^{\sub})$ is a dcpo?

Comment: Doesn't $\subseteq$ always work?

Comment: As Wojowu suggests, use $\subseteq$. The intersection of a family of subdcpos is a subdcpo, so the set of subdcpos is a complete lattice, and therefore a dcpo.